# How to return a map of reducers in getReducers(): ActionReducerMap<fromFeature.State>?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm trying to inject **feature reducers** when composing state through NgRx feature modules.

```js
import { NgModule, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { StoreModule, ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';

import * as fromFeature from './reducers';

export const FEATURE_REDUCER_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<ActionReducerMap<fromFeature.State>>('Feature Reducers');
```

What I am supposed to return here?

```js
export function getReducers(): ActionReducerMap<fromFeature.State> {
  // map of reducers
  return {
  
  };
}
```

I tried

```js
export function getReducers(): ActionReducerMap<fromFeature.State> {
      // map of reducers
      return {
          reducerA: FeatureAReducer
      };
    }
```

But it gives the error *Object literal may only specify known properties*.

The rest of module code:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forFeature('feature', FEATURE_REDUCER_TOKEN),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: FEATURE_REDUCER_TOKEN,
      useFactory: getReducers
    }
  ]
})
export class FeatureModule { }
```

Comment: are you planning to have more than one `StoreModule` based on the feature?

Comment: I have multiple features with their own reducers.

Comment: @vulp your question is already a while ago but I am interested why you want to inject a reducers? What is the intention/reason behind it? It would be good if you could clear that up (Unfortunately, I could not find anything on the internet so I'm looking for developers who can possibly explain to me). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I thought that each reducer, whether it is root or feature reducer, returns a new state object. But actually it doesn't. What feature reducer does, it returns only the segment of the state which it updates.

From the [ngrx/platform/example-app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/127ccc99663442ea1a902e459ae9fb1041fd7f80/example-app/app/reducers/index.ts):

> we treat each reducer like a table in a database. This means our
> top level state interface is just a map of keys to inner state types.